# Creating a dynamic Google group update from a Google form

Tags: google-sheets, google-groups

Just looking for the final piece of code for this. I currently use the code below to pull contact info from a form responses sheet and auto add to an existing group.

I'll be adding a trigger to run every time the form is completed, however I need to change the code to only add info from the LAST ROW. Otherwise it will re-add all the contacts every time the form is completed, instead of just the most recent entry.

```
function addContact() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i =0; i<data.length; i++) { 
var column = data[i];
var firstName = column[1]; 
var lastName = column[2];      
var emailAdd = column[3];
var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(firstName, lastName, emailAdd);
var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Group Name');
debugger;
group.addContact(contact);
}
}
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code, I guess:

```
function addContact() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
   var data = dataRange.getValues();
   var LastDataRow = data[data.length - 1];
   var firstName = LastDataRow[1]; 
   var lastName = LastDataRow[2];      
   var emailAdd = LastDataRow[3];

   // and so on...
}
```

This part of code: `var LastDataRow = data[data.length - 1];` gives you the last row data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read the data from the spreadsheet at all.

Rather, your event handler for the form submission can receive an object containing all of the data for that particular submission.

Details here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Would end up looking something like this:

```
function addContact(e) 
{
  var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(
    e.namedValues["First Name"].toString(),
    e.namedValues["Last Name"].toString(),
    e.namedValues["email Address"].toString());
  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Group Name');
  debugger;
  group.addContact(contact);
}
```